# Wechat mini program app open support conversation

Tags: javascript, wechat, wechat-miniprogram

I am developing mini program application for WeChat. Is it possible to open normal wechat conversation with support from my application? My goal is that user has possibility to communicate with our support team. I tried to find in official doc but with no success.

Thanks for responses

Answer (score 0):

guy.I know there is a way to implement it.There is an **open-type** called contact in button component.For example:

```
<button type="default" size="{{100}}" open-type="contact">
contact
```

There is a link for it.Hope that this may be helpful. [button for wechat](https://developers.weixin.qq.com/miniprogram/en/dev/component/button.html)